# Java Type, Value comparison

Tags: java, types, comparison

I was trying to see what is true table for some Type in Java.

And i cant understand way top one returns true and one below false ?

```
public class CompareTypes{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // -------------------------------------
        Integer AA = 12;
        Integer BB = 12;
        System.out.println( AA == BB ); // true

        // -------------------------------------
        Integer a = 128;
        Integer b = 128;
        System.out.println( a == b ); // false


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing an artifact of autoboxing.

`Integer` objects have different object id's, which mean that that two different `Integer` objects will be `false` for `==`. However, the `valueOf` method caches the first 127 values of the `Integer` object. When you create an `Integer` between -128 and +127, via its valueOf static factory then you get the exact same object. When you create one with a value >= 128 then you get a whole new object every time, with a different id and so not responding intuitively to the `==` call.

Autoboxing uses the `valueOf` method to do the autoboxing, which is why the object references created as `Integer` objects from `int` literals less than 128 work. The lines creating two `Integer` objects of value 128, however, create two different objects.

The moral of the story is

- try to use `.equals()` for value types
- beware of mixing up literal types and boxed types.

https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/boxing_and_caches_integer_valueof